# Getting the type a polymorphically associated element in a controller (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models: **Post** (`has_many` votes as `votable`), **Comment** (`has_many` votes as `votable`) and **Votes** (`belongs_to` votable).

**This is votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @votable = WHAT_TO_PLACE_HERE?.find(params[:id])

    if @votable.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
      @notice = 'You already voted'
    else
      @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
      @votable.reload
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Relevant schema:

```
  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "total_votes", :default => 0
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_comments_on_micropost_id_and_user_id"

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "comments_count", :default => 0, :null => false
    t.integer  "total_votes",    :default => 0
  end

  create_table "votes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "polarity"
    t.integer  "total"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I need  way to find the type of the votable element (**Post** or **Comment**) so I can assign it to **@votable**. Any suggestions to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %><br />
```

**routes.rb:**

```
 get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', as: 'vote_up'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type is passed via `params`, you can do this:

```
params[:votable_type].constantize.find(params[:id])
```

Please check the documentation for [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize).

You can send the type by appending it as an argument to `vote_up_path`:

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post, :votable_type => 'Post'), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %>
```

Like this it will be added as a get parameter, which shouldn't be a problem. If you don't like this, you have to change your route and add `:votable_type` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! One question, is `:type` referring to the `:votable_type` column in the `votes` table (shown above)?

Comment: Yes, it is referring to `:votable_type`. Sorry, it my answer would have been clearer if I'd used `params[:votable_type]` instead of `params[:type]`.

Comment: hey I just realized that there is no `votable_type` until the vote is created (and that code is after the one you provide here). That's why it didn't work for me. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Well, you have to set the parameter manually from where you call this controller action. In the view probably. You have to add something like `:votable_type => 'Post'` to your `button_to` or `link_to`. If you update the question with your view code I can give a more precise answer.

Comment: Ok added the view. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your edit. This should work. Please let me know if something is unclear. Good luck.